# JQuery: Google Maps "bounce" using JQuery Bounce package

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Does anyone know of a way to make a Google Maps marker "bounce" using JQuery [Bounce](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Bounce) package?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the marker to bounce when it's finished dragging, you can do it straight from the API.  Just set [bouncy](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarkerOptions.bouncy) to true.  You can even adjust the [gravity](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarkerOptions.bounceGravity).

Comment: This won't work in V3, only V2. V3 has no bouncyness, in fact the marker doesn't even pick up off the page.